# Formatting time in PHP rows

Tags: php, mysql, time, if-statement

I'm currently using this code:

```
     if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    $count=0;
    $day = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<b>";
            if ($day=='1') { echo "Sunday - ";} else if ($day=='3') { echo "Monday - "; } else if ($day=='5') { echo "Tuesday - "; } else if ($day=='7') { echo "Wednesday - "; } else if ($day=='9') { echo "Thursday - "; } else if ($day=='11') { echo "Friday - "; } else if ($day=='13') { echo "Saturday - "; } else { echo "";}
            if ($row["open"] == 0 && $row["close"] == 0) {
     if ($day % 2 == 1) {
         echo "closed";
     }

}
            else{
            echo "</b>" . $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] . " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
            if ($count % 2 !=0 ){ echo  "<br/><br/>"; } }
$count++;
$day++;

        }
    } else {
            echo "Error";
    }
```

which displays an output such as:

```
 Sunday 09:00:00 - 15:00:00  16:00:00 - 20:00:00
 Monday 09:00:00 - 15:00:00  16:00:00 - 20:00:00
```

I would like to format these times so that only the hour and minute is shown (basically, remove the seconds). Could someone tell me how I'd do this please?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well, I kind of gave up formatting his code. @experimentX even the brightest of programmers are human you know. :)

Comment: @ChristianSciberras well, yes i suppose :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your $row["open"] and $row["close"] variable with substr and cut last three characters:

```
substr($row["open"], 0, -3);
substr($row["close"], 0, -3);
```

Will look like this:

```
echo "</b>" . substr($row["open"], 0, -3) . "-" . substr($row["close"], 0, -3) . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

Comment: This works great so I'm using this method. Thanks, and thanks to everyone else who answered :)

Comment: Don't know why I get downvotes from users, but anyway :) Your welcome.

Comment: Why the downvote? It works, is reasonably clean, and solves the OP's problem so well he accepted the answer. There are some fancier functions to be used but they would depend on knowing the exact internal format of "open".

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
date( "H:i", strtotime( $row["open"] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "</b>" . substr($row["open"], 5) . "-" . substr($row["close"], 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
substr($row["open"], 0, -3)

substr($row["close"], 0, -3)
```